# Reading character streams in Java

Tags: java

The InputStream class provide streams for reading byte data while the Reader classes provide streams for the character data.
For reading character data from the stream, we make use of InputStreamReader,  which is actually a bridge that converts byte streams to character streams.
Isnt it  possible to read character data directly from the stream, instead of reading it initially as a byte steam and then converting it into a character stream?

Answer (score 4):

No it isn't.

One of the reasons is that depending on the character encoding used by the file, a same character may be represented with a different number of bytes.

Take `é` as an example (note the accent):

- in ISO-8859-1, it will be one byte;
- in UTF-8, it will be two bytes;
- in UTF-32, it will be 4 bytes!

And this is why it is of vital importance, when you open a `Reader`, to select the correct character encoding (that is what the [`Charset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) class embodies in Java; see also [`CharsetDecoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html) and [`CharsetEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html)).

The same consideration applies to, for instance, HTTP, XML, etc: all these technologies have one way or another to specify what character encoding is used, so that a "reader" be able to read it correctly.

(and this is without even mentioning that a same character may be, depending on the encoding used, represented by a different set of bytes... Remember EBCDIC?)

Answer (score 0):

The input stream reads the **raw bytes** whereas the character are derived from the stream depending on the **Character encoding**.

Regarding *your question*, you cannot read character directly form stream as there are no characters but only sequence of bytes.You will need character stream to convert the bytes into character.